# What's the best practice when an AngularJS directive has a lot of bindings in its isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, reusability, angular-directive, design-principles

Suppose each card-item directive needs to know a lot of outside contexts and acts accordingly.

We could make a service to monitor the outside world, and inject the service into card-item directive, like:

```
scope: {
  item: '=',
  service: '=',
}

<card-item item="card" 
           service="ItemService">
</card-item>
```

This seems like a bad practice, because the directive **knows too much** about the service (e.g. calls the service's functions inside directive).

Many posts about AngularJS best practices suggest **isolation**, like following.

But it still doesn't feel right here:

```
scope: {
  item: '=',
  isSelected: '&',
  inSelectMode: '&',
  inMoldMode: '&',
  onToggleSelect: '&',
  onTogglePreview: '&',
  onToggleSort: '&',
  onDelete: '&',
  isPreviewing: '&',
  isSorting: '&',
  locales: '=',
  printUrl: '=',
}

<card-item item="card" 
           is-selected="ItemService.isSelected(card)"
           in-select-mode="ItemService.inSelectMode()"
           in-mold-mode="ItemService.inMoldMode()"
           on-toggle-select="ItemService.toggleSelect(card)"
           on-toggle-preview="ItemService.togglePreview(card)"
           on-toggle-sort="ItemService.toggleSortMode()"
           on-delete="ItemService.removeParticle(card)"
           is-previewing="card === entityInPreview"
           is-sorting="ItemService.inSortMode()"
           locales='LocaleService.currentLocales'
           print-url="getPrintUrl(card)">
</card-item>
```

What's your suggestion?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: why don't you call the service from the directive controller?

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary to divide the directive `card-item` into smaller directive, which will carry out specific tasks. For example, to create a directive `card-item-print` for print or download. For example, to create a directive `card-item-preview` for preview. And so on.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko. There is a "Preview" button inside `card-item`. When a `card-item` is in preview, the "Preview" button needs to be highlighted (while other `card-item`s "Preview" buttons are not). That's why a `card-item` must know the outside context ("whether I'm the one in preview, among other `card-items`"). Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to call the service methods form the directive controller,

```
xApp.directive('xDirective', function(itemService, LocaleService, getPrintUrl) {
    function controller() {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            isSelected: ItemService.isSelected(card),
            inSelectMode: "similar to above",
            inMoldMode: "similar to above",
            onToggleSelect: "similar to above",
            onTogglePreview: "similar to above",
            onToggleSort: "similar to above",
            onDelete: "similar to above",
            isPreviewing: "similar to above",
            isSorting: "similar to above",
            locales: "similar to above",
            printUrl: "similar to above"
        })    
    }

    return {
        controller: controller,
        scope: {
            card: '=',
            item: '='
        }
    }
});
```

you can also try to split this directive into smaller sub directives.